# Rubys on rails - Using seperator in a map.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, mapping, super

I have the following method,

```
def providers
  if super && super.any?(&:name)
    super.map(&:name).join(",<br>").html_safe
  else
    "--"
  end
end
```

Providers has following schema,

```
"providers": [
  {
    "name": "",
    "relationship": ""
  }
 ]
```

If the `providers` array has no names then I'm getting `--` which is fine. If all the elements have name in it then I get something like name1,name2,name3. thats fine too. But when I have a provider with name and one without name, I get `name1,` or `,name2`. How do I get rid of these commas when I do a join with an empty element. How do I construct the logic. PLease help,.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use [compact](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#compact-method) to avoid any nil value in your array.

```
def providers
  if super && super.any?(&:name)
    super.map(&:name).compact.join(",<br>").html_safe
  else
    "--"
  end
end

# Example
[ "a", nil, "b", nil, "c" ].compact! #=> [ "a", "b", "c" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
def providers
  providers_with_names = super.keep_if {|p| p.name.present?}
  if providers_with_names.any?
    providers_with_names.map(&:name).join(",<br />").html_safe
  else
    "--"
  end
end
```

I hope it helps.